# SQL Server - check if store is open

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

I have a table as below

```
StoreName  | TimeOpens   |  DurationInMinutes | DayOfTheWeek
Dog Store  '00:08:00.000'          400              1
Duck Store  '00:08:00.000'        1300              1
Cat Store  '00:08:00.000'         1440              1
```

I need to select all stores that are currently open. Times are stored in UTC so GETUTCDATE() can be used to get current time. The TimeOpens is a `Time` object and not a DATETIME, which is why I am a little confused how to write a query that will get me the correct answer. The scenarios are what if the time overlaps over midnight because the duration is that long as in case of Duck Store or what if the duration is 1440 minutes long meaning that its open 24 hours a day.

I thought about converting it to a DateTime first which would make things easier but then I'm not sure do I get today's date or yesterdays when calculating this. For example if I get today's date and its past midnight then I'm before the store opened which would mean its closed. I have the same problem with choosing the day of the week as if its past midnight its technically next day but it could still be open from previous day.

```
SELECT *
FROM Stores
WHERE GETUTCDATE() > CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE()), 10) + ' ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, S.[TimeOpens], 120), 12) AS DATETIME)
```

Edit, the query should somehow include dayoftheweek as well because each day could have a different schedule. its a 1-7 index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
where (cast(getutcdate() as time) >= timeopens and
       datediff(minute, cast(getutcdate() as time), timeopens) <= duration
      ) or
      (cast(utcdate() as time) < dateadd(minute, duration, timeopens) and
       day(dateadd(minute, duration, cast(timeopens as datetime))) > 0
      )
```

Comment: What about DayOfWeek? Part of my problem is figuring out if its open from day before or of it its open from today. Each day could have a different schedule.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this condition to get if its still a valid opening hours.

```
SELECT *
FROM Stores
WHERE
datediff(mi, 
        dateadd(mi, DurationInMinutes,cast(concat(convert(DATE, getutcdate()), ' ', TimeOpens) as datetime))
    , getutcdate()) < 0
```